# Optimal distance to AFK for creeper farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I build this creeper farm with a cat and waterflow mechanics to farm gunpowder but I cant find a good spot to afk in.

here is a screenshot of the place, I've put carpets to prevent spiders from spawning and I've put wooden trapdoors on top so only creepers can spawn in here.

The cat in the middle scares the creepers that then fall in the water stream and get taken to a magma block which kills them in about 20 seconds.

It's built under the ocean and I've lit up the caves surrounding the farm so spawn rate should be good.

When I come close to the area and enter the farm I get a few creepers spawning and then it all shuts down.

[image]

I've tried standing here -

[image]

which is about 30-ish blocks away from the center of the farm

and I've tried standing on top of it like this

[image]

I've been afk for hours but no creepers spawn.

I know that mobs will not spawn more than 128 blocks away from a player, and if they are 32-128 blocks away from a player they will start to randomly spawn and despawn. The optimal distance I thought would be around 30-ish but the creepers aren't spawning.

Does anyone have any idea why they don't spawn at all and at what distance I should be AFK in order to get it to run?

Comment: There was a thing implemented which prevented mobs from spawning if you weren't in the chunk or something like that. When i found out about it, it ruined my mob farm.

Comment: So that would mean i need to be in the same chunk -> no more than 16 blocks away from the most far away block -> mobs only spawn 24 blocks away from a player. Am I missing something ?

Comment: i think that question is better asked for myself. am i missing something in my own experiences ... maybe it is to do with how they are creepers? is there anything online about this stuff?

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn  - jump to SPAWN CONDITIONS for MOBS Spawn Conditions
The following rules apply to all mobs:

Can only spawn 24 blocks spherical radius or further from the player.
Cannot spawn if the block below them is air.
Cannot spawn if that mob would collide with an existing mob.
Cannot spawn on slabs or carpet.

Comment: @DenislavKaragiozov What is your question then? It's right there, where you linked to.

Comment: But it doenst work :D Thats the issue! I am standing exactly 30 blocks away from the center of the mob spawner on the same height level, and nothing spawns inside...

Comment: My curiousity, does this happen to be in that same world that you had an issue with a slime chunk a while back?

Comment: Same. I think the problem with that slime chunk was that there were many mobs around it, the exact same reason why I made this creeper farm in the middle of the ocean and lit up the little cave around it...

Comment: I checked that position out in spectator mode.  You have caves all around.  You also have a large abandoned mineshaft.  The fact that is spawns for a little bit and then stops, leads me to suspect you have too many hostile mobs spawning elsewhere.

Comment: Christ I can never seem to find a good spot.... I figured its only the little cave thats around. Well im not dying for gunpowder anyway, I'll see what I will do with it :/ thanks again for your effort thats a great way to scout the area !

Comment: If you build it in the sky, up near build height, you can afk near it and you will be beyond 128 from the ground preventing spawns elsewhere.  You have to tower to get up there but it eliminates trying to find the perfect place or searching for caverns to light.  If you build it above an ocean and happen to fall off, you won't die.

Comment: Good point will work on that once I find enough time to invest ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is good that your farm is low in the world if you are lower there are more spawns, however you need to light up all the caves within a 128 radius. Otherwise mobs spawn there filling up the mob cap in a singleplayer world this is 70 mobs, if the mobcap is full, there will be no spawns.

Answer (score 2):

The entire area where mobs are meant to be (spawn platforms, drop chute, kill platforms) must be within 128 blocks from you - any farther and the creepers will despawn. Also, at least the spawn platforms must be more than 24 blocks away; mobs don't spawn any closer to the player - so when you come to peek into your farm, all spawns freeze. Anywhere in between is fine.

So, for optimal results, your afking platform should be slightly less than 128 blocks above the lowest part of the farm (the killing floor); additionally to benefit from the low location of the farm in increased spawn rates, it's good to have anything above the spawn platforms be as low as possible - so build the platform slightly to the side, not directly above the spawn platforms.

Note lighting *all* the caves within 128 blocks (sphere) from your afking spot is *crucial*. Even a small unlit area will keep spawning mobs eating into the mob cap and gradually making your farm grind to a halt as a crowd of mobs accumulates in a single unlit cave. If you're unable to find all the spots, a rather poor but better than nothing way around that is to despawn all mobs periodically - so you may expand your elevator/tower of your farm to (62+128=) y=190, a spot you'd visit occasionally to despawn all the mobs in missed, unlit caverns (but also unfortunately inside the farm too) and restore the rates to 100% for a time.

Let me add, utilizing the ocean bottom was a pretty smart move as only a little section of the sphere remains to be lit up. You will get the drowned occasionally spawning and spawn-proofing against them is nearly impossible, but their number is sufficiently low they won't ruin the farm.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be about 235 blocks on the y axis or the game will stop spawning mobs because on the amount of entities around the area so the higher the better

Comment: I’ve made plenty of farms and this is the only solution I could come up with when making the and it works the reason this is the problem in because you afk spot is underground so your farm would be to with creepers and things like that keep them as high as possible

Comment: Or other mob will spawn in other locations instead and not in you farm

Comment: You can [edit] your answer if you want to add additional information

Comment: Where in the world did you get 235 blocks, for an under-ocean farm?! That puts the farm outside the despawn sphere.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure they spawn underground as much as they do above ground. The game probably sees the farm as a house and there's probably code in the game preventing creepers from spawning inside player-built buildings, and probably buildings in general. It's been a while since I've played the game though, so correct me if I'm wrong.
  -So maybe try removing the roof.
  -It could also be the cat. Maybe creepers don't spawn around them out of fear.

Comment: Btw nice computer

Comment: lol as far as I know, everything you just said is false. The roof is necessary for the light, player built buildings don't mean anything, and cat's allow creepers to spawn. They just don't go towards the cat, and instead run from it.